# Syntax highlighting with Chili

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax-highlighting

I want to use jquery Chili plugin for syntax highlighting a piece of code thats generated on the fly, but its not working for the same, because the code is inserted into the #output div on page load.

When I tried chili with static examples, it worked but not on the dynamically generated code. Is there any workaround?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Chili plugin broke with jQuery 1.4.x, not sure what it was though.